# How to best apply colliders on a rough 3D shape

Tags: unity, 3d, collider

I have a 3D model for a level in unity. I want to add colliders to it. What is the best type of collider for this model? And,it is 3D

[image: Top-down view of level]

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include a framework / tech tag. Multiple frameworks have colliders, please include the tag for the one you're using, for example: [tag:unreal],  [tag:unity], [tag:godot], etc.

Comment: Also, documentation for most frameworks will let you know basic stuff, like if it's 2d or 3d. Questions that don't show basic research effort tend to attract down votes.

Answer (score 1):

There really is just one realistic option, and that's a [Mesh Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html). Make sure you mark the object as "Static" and enable mesh cooking on your mesh collider in order to improve performance. The alternative would be to manually create a separate Box Collider for every single wall in the level, which would be a very tedious and error-prone task.

When your level is too complex for a mesh collider because you have lots of high-detail geometry in it, then it can make sense to go back to your 3d modeling program and create a simplified version of the level mesh which you then export separately and use as the mesh for the mesh collider.

---

Oh, and just by the way: Do you know [Pro Builder](https://unity3d.com/unity/features/worldbuilding/probuilder)? This optional package for Unity allows you to create and edit levels directly in the scene editor.